# Need help for stopping spam inquiries

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make your site anti-bot?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot)

I am not a web developer, nor have I the required knowledge to grasp this situation.

I have a small company with a modest web site where I market properties.
Recently, my website is being bombarded with spam inquires. Here are some examples:

"It was dark when I woke. This is a ray of sunhsnie."
"This is exactly what I was looknig for. Thanks for writing!"
"What a joy to find sooemne else who thinks this way."

As you can see, all of them has typos, probably for tracking the work done.

I would be glad if someone can offer a solution to stop this nonsense.

Thank you for sharing your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "inquiries?" The stuff you quote looks like fairly standard comment spam, but you could also be referring to messages getting dumped into a contact form, for example. If your site's being managed by a CMS of some kind, it would also probably be good to mention what it is, as solutions are likely going to start with the application of some spam prevention plugin or other.

Comment: Likewise I'd need a little more info to answer. It the inquiry in the form of an email address such as, "please contact inquiry@example.com" or is a form on your website that needs filled out. If the latter, what system does your website run on? e.g. wordpress or something custom made. Perhaps a link to the site might allow use to see for our selves who things are setup.

Answer (score 0):

See these links

[Prevent malicious bots from posting spam](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot)

[Effective captcha solutions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/194/effective-captcha-solutions)

[Recommended Spam Best Practices](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8046/recommended-spam-best-practices)